# Read full tabel in full table

Tags: lua

How can I read a full table in a full table?

```
test = {}
test["Hello"] = "World"
test["tab"] = {}
test["tab"]["example"] = "ex"
test["tab"]["whats"] = "up"
test["seta"] = {}
test["seta"]["ask"] = "question"
test["seta"]["hard"] = {}
test["seta"]["hard"]["cool"] = "lua"
```

This is a exaple Table I would like to read. I need a table with this content:

```
"test.Hello" "World"
"test.tab.example" "ex"
"test.tab.whats" "up"
"test.seta.ask" "question"
"test.seta.hard.cool" "lua"
```

Left is the indexer and right the content. Has anybody a idea? That table I would read can also be

```
Thats["a"]["very"]["big"]["table"]
```

Or biger. Thankyou for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

First, solve the problem for tables with key strings and key values (i.e., no nesting tables):

```
function longkeys(object)
    local out = {}
    for key, value in pairs(object) do
        table.insert(out, {longkey = key, value = value})
    end
    return out
end

for _, pair in pairs(longkeys(test)) do
    print("test." .. pair.longkey, pair.value)
end
```

This will correctly capture `Hello` mappin to `World`, but it will map, e.g., `tab` to `table: 00B6A488`.

We can modify the `longkeys` function to recursively inspect `value` whenever it's a table:

```
function longkeys(object)
    local out = {}
    for key, value in pairs(object) do
        if type(value) == "table" then
            local keysof = longkeys(value)
            for _, pair in pairs(keysof) do
                pair.longkey = key .. "." .. pair.longkey
                table.insert(out, pair)
            end
        else
            table.insert(out, {longkey = key, value = value})
        end
    end
    return out
end
```

This relies on observing the recursive structure of these 'longkeys'. If `s[k]` is `t` and `L` is a longkey of `t` with value `v`, then `k .. "." .. L` is a longkey of `s` with value `v`.

Note that the solution assumes the structure of the table is entirely string keys => string values | tables of that form.

This won't work with other data types, or with cyclical tables.

Also, keep in mind that the 'longkeys' spit out by this function aren't necessarily valid Lua expressions for getting values out; consider a table with keys

```
local bad = {
    ["break"] = "break",
    ["i have a space"] = "space",
    ["i.have.dots"] = "dots",
    ["i\\have\"quotes"] = "quotes",
}
```

The output will give

```
bad.break
bad.i have a space
bad.i.have.dots
bad.i\have"quotes
```

none of which are valid ways to access the `bad` table

Answer (score -1):

```
local function f(r, t, p)
   for k, v in pairs(t) do
      if type(v) == "table" then 
         f(r, v, p..k..".")
      else 
         r[p..k] = v
      end
   end
end

local result = {}
f(result, test, "test.")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @kayess - If you consider my post as low-quality or not suitable for SO, please use "downvote" button.  Three downvotes and I will delete it.

Comment: No, I haven't wrote that. I wrote that it lacks explanation on what the code does and I still think that.

Comment: @kayess - I like short answers and short code without redundant words.  I don't like to read long texts.  And I try to post "concentrated-idea" answers.  My code is rather simple.  Which line of code should be explained?

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) on meta, and you can search there for more on explaining why code only answers are not pretty well _without_ explanation.

Comment: @kayess - SO is Q&A site.  It is not a place for full-fledged tutorials.  You should have some background (Lua basics) to understand question and answer.  Let me ask you again: what exactly should be explained in my code?

Comment: Variable names, and an explanation on why recursion is both appropriate and effective in this situation. *Not* just one-liners either, help the asker to understand these concepts so he isn't just abusing what you wrote for him, and can instead apply the new knowledge in future scenarios. SO mightn't be a tutorial site, but it certainly isn't a database of code snippets, if a person asks a question, they deserve not only *what* they should do, but the understanding of *how* it works and can be expanded upon. An answer isn't just a solution, it's a response which helps them to solve a problem.